# Link_to Ruby on rails - undefined method `post_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code:

```
<%= @r2_blog_posts = Refinery::Blog::Post.recent(2) %>
<%= link_to(@r2_blog_posts.first) do %>
    <%= image_tag(@r2_blog_posts.first.teaser_first_img) %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting this error for second line: undefined method `post_path' for #<#:0x0000000841c168>
teaser_first_img is returning src attribute of the first image in teaser

Comment: Rails is looking for a `post_path` url helper and can't find one. Judging from the namespacing on the `Post` model, the route is probably namespaced too. Run `rake routes` at the console and edit the output into your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply: here is the gist https://gist.github.com/2510457 with rake routes output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used this engine, but I think that the posts - is a nested or namespaced resource. So you need to know at first path for post: `rake routes`
and then use something like: `link_to blog_post_path(@r2_blog_posts.first)` - change `blog_post_path` to actual path

Comment: Thanks for your reply: here is the gist https://gist.github.com/2510457 with rake routes output

Comment: It seems I'm guessing, you should use "link_to blog_post_path(@r2_blog_posts.first)" according to 71th line of your gist.

Comment: Mikhail D. it's correct. I would kindly ask you to give me a short explanation of how did you find it (I'm new to ruby on rails)

Comment: I just assumed that in this engine posts have namespace 'blog'. In question, why you should call such "path", I think this guide covers better then I: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Answer (score 0):

You must have defined on your routes something like

```
resources :posts
```

or

```
match 'post/:id' => 'posts#show', :as => :post
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply: here is the gist https://gist.github.com/2510457 with rake routes output.